# Specify next version of document while uploading

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am in the process of upgrading my SharePoint Site to 2013. Previously, I used to store all the versions of the document as a separate file, now I am writing one application to upload them as versions in the new SharePoint.

The problem here is, there might be some missing versions in between, 
for example: I have three versions of same file & second version is missing.

Is there any that I could upload first version as 0.1 & next file as 0.3, keeping 0.2 unavailable. (As it was missing from original source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't skip minor or major versions in SharePoint. But there is a time consuming workaround. Every time you save a document in a SharePoint library, with minor versioning switched on, it will increment the minor version. So if you don't have version 0.2, you can add a space character in the document and saving the document, its version will increment to 0.2. At this stage you can upload your 0.3 version.